# RAM in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, adobe, memory

I wanted to know if my way of editing is going to hurt anything on my computer or not.

So I have my cache, scratch, and project folder set to the same drive separate from OS and adobe app drive and 16 GB of ram.

When I drop files from the drive onto my premier timeline, RAM and disk usage shoots up taking all the RAM then goes down to 11 GB or so.

Is it normal, or is there a problem I'm not seeing?

Thanks for your time and patience, I'm completely new to editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the RAM usage inside Premiere Pro performing the following actions:

Edit -> Preferences -> Memory -> RAM reserved for other applications.

Try setting it up to comfortable amount of RAM as You might have it set too low.

Comment: is the problem im looking that its not loading stuff onto the ram and just working off files from the hard drive?

Comment: @nunez7890 Well what You are describing up above I would call "normal" Premiere Pro behaviour. It is far from optimal using only 1 drive for all the data that is being used by the software. The ideal situation would be to have:
1. OS drive.
2. Application drive.
3. Cache drive.
4. Used footage drive.
5. Export drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple partitions on the same spinning rust drive (I.e. not an SSD), it doesn’t buy you much performance. Either use physically separate drives or upgrade to an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

> When I drop files from the drive onto my premier timeline, RAM and
> disk usage shoots up taking all the RAM then goes down to 11 GB or so.

Probably it's normal, because Premiere use all available RAM at first, then it cleans up part of ram that it don't use or maybe locate data from RAM to SWAP file.